Screen randomly flickering in Ubuntu 24.04
It seems I'm not the only one having this problem. There's no much answers for this issue in the site. The thing is that the screen turns off randomly in Ubuntu. My PC is a Lenovo ThinkCentre M70q. This issue is incredibly annoying. It happens when click, installing a package, or doing anything.
What can I do to solve this issue? I'm not an expert on Ubuntu or Linux whatsoever.

Is it with the main screen or secondary one?

This issue is probably related to
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2062951. Adding intel_iommu=igfx_off in the kernel parameters is a temporary fix until ubuntu releases a permanent solution. Related QA can be found here Sometimes the screen flickers specifically on Ubuntu 24.04
